# How to upload photo, edit it with Aviary and then submit through a front-end form?

Tags: file-uploads, custom-fields, forms, image, image-path

I'm not an experienced user and would like to make something complicated: I'd like to use aviary editor to edit photo's on form submit. I need a form where user's can upload their image, edit it with aviary and submit it. Aviary provides a temporary link to the new edited image, I want this edited image to not be sent to the server until the whole form is submitted. How should i go about doing this?

I had hoped to pass the url into the input file path.

How can i do it?

should be something similar to http://freeonlinephotoeditor.org with submit instead download

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at @objectivehtml's extremely powerful [Photo Frame add-on](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/photo-frame).  There is also a [demo of it running on the front end](https://objectivehtml.com/photo-frame/demo). To get the same number of editing options, you may also need his companion [Photo Frame Button Pack](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/photo-frame-button-pack).  There are several other packs for the add-on, for things like focus, text, filters, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you'd like to roll your own module, try this module $25 which uses avairy: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/image-editor

Comment: Thank you Stuartmcd69, Image-editor it's a nice add-on but I need a front-end Aviary editor where users can edit their photos before submit the form, not in the Control panel side..